# OS X Status Bar Application with a title in two lines

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mountain-lion, statusbaritem

I'm an old iOS developer and now I want to make a simple OS X status bar application. I need to put a *title* at the NSStatusItem but it should be in two lines, like **iStatPro** network feature.

How should I add it?

Comment: I am not at a Mac that I can put an example together for you. But  You basically add a custom NSView to the NSStatusItem. look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000248-BBCFFDJA

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple example.   This example  shows two lines with two simple blinking lights.

It uses a NSView  (Custom view) with two NSTextFields and two NSImageWells inside of it.

The red and green light images are added to the project and set to the Image wells in IB.

[image]

[image]

**.m**

```
//
//  AppDelegate.m
//  Drawing Strings
//
//  Created by Mark Hunte on 07/10/2013.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Mark Hunte. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
NSStatusItem *statusItem;

-(void)awakeFromNib{

    //-- SET UP ATTRIBUTED TEXT FOR THE LINES. WHICH GIVES US MORE CONTROL OVER THE TEXT IF WE WANT IT.
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];


    //--SET THE HEIGHT OF THE LINES
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 12.f;


    //-- TEXT FOR NSTEXTFIELD 1
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc]
                                            initWithString:@"Line 1"attributes: [NSDictionary
                                                                                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,paragraphStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ,nil]];
     //-- TEXT FOR NSTEXTFIELD 2
    NSAttributedString *attributedString2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc]

                                             initWithString:@"Line 2"attributes: [NSDictionary
                                                                                  dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,paragraphStyle,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName ,nil]];


    //--- SET THE TEXT
    [_textField1  setAttributedStringValue:attributedString];
    [_textField2  setAttributedStringValue:attributedString2];


    //--- SET UP THE STATUS BAR
    NSStatusBar *bar = [NSStatusBar systemStatusBar];
    statusItem =  [bar statusItemWithLength: NSVariableStatusItemLength]  ;


    //-- CONSTRAIN THE CUSTOM VIEWS SIZE
    [_customView setFrameSize: NSMakeSize(50, 22)];


    //--- ADD THE VIEW TO THE STATUS BAR ITEM

    [statusItem setView:_customView];

    //-- MAKE SURE IT DISPLAYS
    [ _customView display];
    [_customView  setNeedsDisplay:TRUE];

    //-- HIDE ONE OF THE IMAGE VIEWS
    [_greenLight   setHidden:TRUE];


}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{


    //-- SET UP A TIME TO BLINK THE TWO IMAGE VIEW LIGHTS

NSTimer *    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(blinkLights) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [timer fire];

}

-(void)blinkLights{

    //-- IF IMAGE VIEW IS HIDDEN UNHIDE IT, IF SHOWN HIDE IT.

    [_greenLight   setHidden:![_greenLight isHidden]];
    [_redLight   setHidden:![_redLight isHidden]];


}


@end
```

I use two textfields as I think this will give better control if needed. But you can use one and newline the text. @"Line 1\nLine 2"

I also had to set a Maximum line hight to help with the text alignment and had to fiddle with the constraints in  IB.

But the result is  two lines with blinking lights:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Subclass an NSView where you draw your text manually (search for drawing NSString), then add the view to the Status Item.