# How to draw two lines of text in a NSView subclass ? (macOS system tray)

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsstatusbar

I'm trying to write two lines of text in the macOS system tray, very much like iStat pro does for the network activity:

[image]

I know I have to subclass NSView to do so, but I can't manage to get it working even for one line:

```swift
class CustomView:NSView {

  override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        let text: NSString = "my string"

        let textRect: NSRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 20)
        text.draw(in: textRect)

  }
}
```

and then:

```swift
let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
statusItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: 100)
let view = CustomView()
view.wantsLayer = true
statusItem.button?.addSubview(view)
```

I've found other threads on stackoverflow:

- [OS X Status Bar Application with a title in two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19211079/os-x-status-bar-application-with-a-title-in-two-lines) : It's in objective C and I can not get it working neither
- [How to show two row of text in a menu bar app in mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189763/how-to-show-two-row-of-text-in-a-menu-bar-app-in-mac-os?rq=1) : explainations are not detailled enough for me unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubt that it's what you are looking for, but this will put two lines of text in a status item:

```
import Cocoa

let app = NSApplication.shared
let statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength:-1)
statusItem.button?.font = NSFont(name:"Menlo Bold", size: 10.0)
statusItem.button!.title = "one\ntwo"
app.run()
```

It's still just one button and I don't see how you will separate the selection of each item.  Perhaps a drop down menu would work better?

Comment: That will do the trick for what I'm trying to do, thank you so much !