# Electron number widget in macOS menubar

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, menubar, system-tray

I'm currently searching for a way to display number values in the macOS menubar. Tools like [iStat Menus 6](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) show that it's possible to display advanced widgets in the macOS menubar like number values and charts, see [here](https://bjango.com/images/mac/istatmenus6/hero-menubars.jpg).

I would like to create a number widget in my electron application. However, I cannot find a way to get started. What I have found is the Tray class from the electron package. It allows to create a tray icon using an image like a png:

```
const path = require('path');
const {
  app,
  Menu,
  Tray,
  } = require('electron');

let tray = null;

app.on('ready', () => {
  tray = new Tray(path.join(__dirname, '/Icon.png'));

  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    tray.on('click', tray.popUpContextMenu);
  }

  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
    {
      label: 'Quit',
      click() { app.quit(); }
    }
  ]);

  tray.setToolTip('Clipmaster');
  tray.setContextMenu(menu);
});
```

How do applications like iStat create such powerful widgets? It does not look like iStat is rendering their widgets to images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Electron has a (limited) way of putting text next to the tray icon in macOS:

```
// API: tray.setTitle(title[, options])
tray.setTitle("foo")
```

- See the [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/tray#traysettitletitle-options-macos) for usage instructions.
- See [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/tray-example) for an example use of this API.

Unfortunately, that's as far as it seems to go. As an abstraction layer to make cross-platform development much easier, Electron often cannot provide all of an OS's native features.

iStat is not using the Electron framework (and is only available for macOS). Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61557717/) to see how you may write multiple lines of text into the status bar using Apple's Cocoa framework.

Comment: I didn't have time to try this (at all), but as an afterthought: writing 2 lines (or more, if that makes any sense) may just be possible: `tray.setTitle("foo\nbar")`